# Entering javascript into test boxes

Tags: javascript, selenium

I was having trouble using the plain Selenium element.sendKeys(value).  I found a javascript solution:

```
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='arguments[1]';", ele, value);
```

(assume jse is set).  I tried this, but as I feared, it is setting value to 'arguments[1]' and is not substituting because it is in single quotes.  I imagine I need the single quotes there.  So how can I get it to substitute?  The ele part is working fine.  And value is a string.

Comment: Is the problem occuring because arguments[1] is enclosed with single quotes?

Comment: ye indeed it is

Comment: If you need the single quotes, you can add them to value before you pass it in.

Comment: value = StringUtils.join("'", value, "'");  ??

Comment: Another question.  This will now fill in the values, but when I click "Finish" (this is a docusign document) it highlights the fields filled in and says they are required.  The text is there, but I think the program may not have noticed that they were set.  Somehow they have to be entered too?  I triedd appending Keys.ENTER to the end but no luck

Comment: Considering this is DocuSign and their main product is designed to avoid this type of thing, you may have to look further at the elements. Do any classes get removed/added when you enter text? Are any javascript handlers called? (I find it odd that `sendKeys()` doesn't work. Are you sure you are targetting the correct element?

Comment: sendKeys() works except each field has a popup box which blocks an element and I get ElementClickInterceptedException (something like that)